# Only ROLE_ANONYMOUS layers and groups showing in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoserver

I have multiple layers and layer groups in GeoServer.

I have created a role "role_x" which give access to some layers. I have removed ROLE_ANONYMOUS access to these and given access to "role_x".

Only the ROLE_ANONYMOUS services show up in ArcMap, not the role_x:s. In QGIS everything works as expected, I can see both ROLE_ANONYMOUS and role_x services using the same URL and login in ArcMap and QGIS.

[image]

What could be causing this?